# WebSphere web container threads blocked while loading JSF Expression Factory

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere

I am using WAS 8, JSF 2 (Apache MyFaces)
During performance testing, we noticed that some of the web container threads are getting blocked while loading JSF Expression Factory. Find log below from thread dump

Any suggestion on how to avoid this will be useful.
Why JSF is loading the classes for every new instance creation of javax.el.expressionfactory?

```
java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627(Compiled Code)) at
javax/el/ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:175(Compiled Code)) at
javax/el/ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:107(Compiled Code)) at
javax/el/BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:404(Compiled Code)) at
javax/el/CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:137(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/el/parser/AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:162(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/el/ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/el/TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/el/parser/AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:67(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/el/ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/el/ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:202(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/el/ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:134(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/compiler/AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:51(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/compiler/UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/compiler/UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:214(Compiled Code)) at
javax/faces/component/UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622(Compiled Code)) at
javax/faces/component/UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1320(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/application/ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/lifecycle/RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85(Compiled Code)) at
org/apache/myfaces/lifecycle/LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239(Compiled Code)) at
javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/cache/servlet/ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/cache/servlet/CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/cache/servlet/CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/cache/servlet/ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224(Compiled Code)) at
com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774(Compiled Code))
```

Comment: It looks as if the WAS classloader is unable to find the EL jar for JSF.  I would think that WAS comes bundled with this, but I wouldn't be sure.  Either way, WAS cannot find this jar.

Comment: @maple_shaft: thanks for the response. The above scenarios is noticed only at heavy load condition, but at normal load, we do not see these blockers. Hence WAS should be finding the JARS. Right?

Comment: That is indeed very strange and have never heard of a problem like this in load testing.  Generally the application will not startup correctly if it cannot find all the classes it needs.  I think that WebSphere's custom classloader may have a bug.  I would suggest talking with IBM technical support as this may be a known bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a failure to find the classes at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a recently resolved (but as yet not shipped in a fixpack) APAR, PM78648.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034243&myns=swgws&mynp=OCSSEQTP&mync=R

I'd suggest opening a ticket with IBM and requesting an interim fix so you can continue your performance testing.